# How to start remote-containers (the VScode extension) for a different platform?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

So I have docker environment, and want to use the [Remote Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) VScode extension to attach my editor to a container.

But I need to specify the platform while building, otherwise it doesn't work

This build command works:

`docker buildx build --file Dockerfile.local --platform linux/amd64 -t webapp . --load`

However, when I use "Open folder in container" option from Remote-containers, I found in the build log that it's being started with this command:

`docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /Users/macbook/webapp/Dockerfile.local -t vsc-webapp-d6a884082a6b83d4c1a0444e21b1d8e0 /Users/macbook/webapp`

So the build Fails.

How can I tell remote-containers to use `--platform linux/amd64` while building?

I tried adding this to devcontainer.json and didn't work:

`"build": { "args": { "DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM": "linux/amd64" }}`

and

`"containerEnv": { "DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM": "linux/amd64" }`

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was adding the platform information directly in Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8-slim
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, couldn't find any other alternative either